# postfix mail receive: how to wait for DNS caching?

Tags: postfix, bind

Postfix server is working with local Bind DNS configured as:

- a recursive DNS
- a caching DNS

Postfix is configured to check incoming client reverse hostname. The problem is that when a new hostname is not into DNS cache, the postfix log an error:

```
450 4.7.1 Client host rejected: cannot find your reverse hostname
```

Consequently this add a delay on mail reception, due to waiting for a new attempt from the client SMTP server.

*My question: Is there a specific postfix parameter in order to wait more longer for DNS response? Is there another solution?*

Comment: It sounds more of a dns configuration problem to me. Do you have "recursion" allowed for your local server, and is it working?

Comment: Yes, in my named.conf I have `allow-recursion { any;  };`

Comment: It seems that for one host not in Bind cache, postfix act as the Bind response is 'host not know' and the second time it's working when Bind cache is not empty !